# Cropping an image by using OpenCV+

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to crop an image by using OpenCV (With Python)

I tried using the code shown here. However it gives some errors.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("paint-horse-running-in-field.jpg")
crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow("paint-horse-running-in-field.jpg", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

The error:  import cv2
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Comment: have you installed the module? what kind of OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the opencv package onto your machine first.

If you have pip on your machine, you can run this in a command prompt:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Then you will be able to import the cv2 module